# Virtual Hosts on a windows machine in local network

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, domain-name-system, virtualhost, local-area-network

I am running an Apache 2.2.21 on Win7 x64, using sucessfully a row of different virtual hosts

- local.projectOne
- local.projectTwo
- ...

So far this was fine, using the hosts file to map'em all to 127.0.0.1. Now I want to do Android/iPhone optimizations, in other words, also other devices in the local network should see the different local devices, so **etc/hosts are not an option**. As of now, they can all access http://mymachinename, but of course only get the default localhost website.

I found plenty of tutorials around the hosts file (which no longer is of use for me), but very little on making known a windows machine in the local network under two names.

Do I have to / can I
a) somehow tell windows to communicate two network names
or
b) do I habe to tinker with my router's built-in (I presume) DNS server. Which is a Fritzbox 7270. Without hard hacks, telnet, ... there seem's not to be an easy solution?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to configure DNS for those names to point to your system (or else configure a hosts file on the devices you're testing with, but I assume that's not an option)

If your router's DNS service isn't capable, then you'll need to set up a more capable DNS server.

Comment: Thank you both. Fritz(box) also confirmed, that this would be the way to go, but they don't have this feature yet (at least an official and easy way to tune the DNS for the local network). I solved my issues by using different ports for the different websites ( http://mymachine:8080, http://mymachine:8181 ). Less pretty, but doing the job...

Answer (score 1):

If you just doing this for testing, its possible that [Posadis](http://posadis.sourceforge.net/sans)  might do the job for you although I haven't tried it.